# How to split a string and parse to Double before storing in a matrix?

Tags: java

I'm working on an assigment from uni, I'm given a set of strings that contain numbers which I split to store in a matrix for later use.

While solving it, I noticed I used `Double.parseDouble` a lot when retreiving the data to do the comparisons and wondered if I can avoid doing that by simply parsing the data at the moment of the split, but I get the message:

`The method parseDouble(String) in the type Double is not  applicable for the arguments (String[])`

When trying to do this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < entries; i++) {
  dataMatrix[i] = Double.parseDouble( input.nextLine().split(" ") );
}
```

Is there a way to achive this? or do I have to convert the string everytime?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I give you an example for your reference:

```
public class HelloWorld{

 public static void main(String []args){
    String data="321213.0 7897.98 12.2212";
    String [] dataArray=data.split(" ");
    for (int i = 0; i < dataArray.length; i++) {
        System.out.println(Double.parseDouble(dataArray[i]));
    }
 }
}
```

Comment: What if I need to collect the data inside the loop? Because first I'm given the number of strings, and the I'm given the strings one at the time.

Answer (score 0):

You must parse all items of `input.nextLine().split(" ")`, not the array `input.nextLine().split(" ")`

Comment: How do I do that? Please excuse me, I'm new to Java and still a bit overwhelmed by having to be specific about everything